# Hashset and List :Which one is efficient way to store list of objects

Tags: c#

Which one of the folowing is efficient way to store list of objects?

```
Hashset<object> listOfObjects = new HashSet<object>();
```

or

```
List<object>listOfObjects = new List<object>();
```

Comment: Efficient in what way? Searching?  Iterating?  Sorting?  Inserting? Note that `List` can contain duplicates, `Hashset` can't.

Comment: Why don't you test for yourself what's better in your use case? [Eric Lippert on performance measuring](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Basically I am trying to implement path planning algorithm and I want this for storing the information about the nodes.